# Confluent Kafka S3 source connector - not a valid AVRO format

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, avro

I am trying to setup a Confluent kafka s3 source connector to read from S3 and add messages to Kafka topic. I am struggling with the formats - it asks for input and output format. What those mean? I could not find good explanataion from docs

[image]

I selected AVRO and AVRO. While saving files to S3, I am saving it in `.avro` format and value to be saved is encoded response from Kafkajs confluent schema registry using following lines

```
const registryId = await this.registry.getLatestSchemaId(subject);
return this.registry.encode(registryId, payload);
```

However I am getting error in connector - `The connector failed because it encountered a file which wasn't in a valid Avro format`.

[image]

I will appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: The S3 source has two different connectors. General and Restore. The restore type expects a format written by the S3 sink, not some Nodejs process. In any case, you should show us the files in the bucket; are any of them not Avro, as the error says?

Comment: Hi @OneCricketeer - Here is the Avro file https://filetransfer.io/data-package/4m9AeQgn#link.

Comment: Sorry, I would prefer not to download random links. Please [edit] your question to include a listing of your bucket. As mentioned, it's possible there could be more than only Avro files there, meaning the error is failing reading non Avro files, as it says. You should also give more details about how that file was created